# angular 4.0 binding issue

Tags: angular, binding, django-rest-framework

I tried to follow Heroes Tutorial from Angular documentation to start learning Angular, but when I started changing few things, some issues occured:

- For my project I'm using Django rest framework as backend, providing API for retrieving my "books items".
  I'm very new in this so I just want to know if the API set up were correct, but I don't know how.
- I started implementing Models in django, then Serializers, ViewSet, and finally the Urls.
- In angular I wrote the Service component, for http request, and a basic html to use this service and show that communication works.
- appcomponent.ts

  ```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { BookService } from './book.service';
  import { Book } from './book';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers: [BookService],

  })
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'app works!';
    books : Book[] = [];
    constructor(private bookService : BookService) { }

    getBooks(): void {
      this.bookService.getBooks().then(books => this.books = books);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.getBooks();
    }
  }
  ```
- appcomponent.html

```html
<ul class="books">
      <li *ngFor="let book of books">
        <span class="badge">{{book.isbn}}</span> {{book.title}}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

- book.ts

  export class Book {
    id: number;
    title: string;
  }
- bookservice.ts

  import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
      import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
      import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
      import { Book } from './book';

  ```
  @Injectable()
  export class BookService {

    private booksUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/books/';
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getBooks(): Promise<Book[]> {
      return this.http.get(this.booksUrl)
                 .toPromise()
                 .then(response => response.json().data as Book[])
                 .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
      console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
      return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }

    getBook(id:number): Promise<Book>{
      const url = `${this.booksUrl}/${id}`;
      return this.http.get(url)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data as Book)
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  }
  ```

When I run this code I have this:

```html
<ul _ngcontent-c0="" class="books">
      <!--bindings={}-->
    </ul>
```

like if bindings doesnt work.
But if i go to "Network" in Chrome, I can see the list of books retrieved from my server

```
[{isbn: "123lko12d", book_title: "Analisi2", pub_date: "2017-06-09T10:12:00Z"},…]
0
:
{isbn: "123lko12d", book_title: "Analisi2", pub_date: "2017-06-09T10:12:00Z"}
book_title
:
"Analisi2"
isbn
:
"123lko12d"
pub_date
:
"2017-06-09T10:12:00Z"
1
:
{isbn: "isijh12432", book_title: "Fisica1", pub_date: "2017-05-17T16:11:02Z"}
book_title
:
"Fisica1"
isbn
:
"isijh12432"
pub_date
:
"2017-05-17T16:11:02Z"
```

I dont really know what im doing wrong...
Thank you for your time and sorry my bad english

Update:
in the console now appears this row:

```
(2) [Object,Object] book.service.ts

0:Object
book_title
:
"Analisi2"
isbn
:
"123lko12d"
pub_date
:
"2017-06-09T10:12:00Z"

1:Object
book_title
:
"Fisica1"
isbn
:
"isijh12432"
pub_date
:
"2017-05-17T16:11:02Z"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service, in your getBooks function, try this :

```
getBooks(): Promise<Book[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.booksUrl)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response =>{
                console.log(response.json());
                return response.json() as Book[];
           })
           .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And put the log in your issue please. The problem I think, is that you use `data`, but you probably don't have it in your response (for instance, in my current project, we set it to `content`)

Comment: omg actually adding that row made my code works properly. I just change the html from {{book.title}} to {{book.book_title}}...

Comment: I also changed the return, as you can see you use `response.json().data` and I use `response.json()`, this is what makes your code works. Don't forget to mark it as resolved !

Comment: Oh, its true, actually i didnt notice it... Tank you so much!